# Use, as part of a string, an object returned as the output of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I have this `Array` of objects:

```
var animals = [
    { name: 'murphy brown the dog', type: 'dog', age: 4, fav_toy: 'squeaky octopus'},
    { name: 'mervin', type: 'cat', age: 1, fav_toy: 'catnip mouse'},
    { name: 'peppercorn', type: 'cat', age: 3, fav_toy: 'lady bug pillow'},
    { name: 'willa', type: 'cat', age: 4, fav_toy: 'jingle ball'},
    { name: 'rhoda', type: 'cat', age: 14, fav_toy: 'your emotions'},
    { name: 'squatch', type: 'dog', age: 4, fav_toy: 'rope toy'},
    { name: 'maya', type: 'dog', age: 15, fav_toy: 'hedgehog'},
    { name: 'sadie', type: 'dog', age: 16, fav_toy: 'paper towel roll'},
    { name: 'max', type: 'hamster', age: 1, fav_toy: 'wooden stick'}
];
```

I was able to create a function which identified the oldest animal in said array.

```
var currentAge = 0;

function oldestAnimal (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].age >= currentAge){
            (currentAge = list[i].age);
        }
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
        if (list[x].age == currentAge) {
            (console.log(list[x]));
        }
    }
}
oldestAnimal(animals);
```

I now need to take the output of the above function, which is:

```
{ name: 'sadie', type: 'dog', age: 16, fav_toy: 'paper towel roll'}
```

And use it to create a string using the values for the `name`, `age`, `type` and `toy` properties.

I've tried dot notation, bracket notation and other combinations that probably were just gibberish. I thought about pushing the output into a new `Array` but I feel like that would be cheating as the instructions are to take the object returned by the function and use it to log the desired sentence to the console.

One attempt was:

```
console.log("My name is " + oldestAnimal(animals).name);
```

Console sent back:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Another attempt was :

```
console.log("My name is " + (oldestAnimal[animals.type]));
```

which resulted in

```
My name is undefined
```

I feel like this second one is a bit closer to where I need to be on this but I would greatly appreciate some assistance on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your first attempt:

```
console.log("My name is " + oldestAnimal(animals).name);
```

… was right … but the function is wrong.

**You have to return the value you want**.

Since the function doesn't have a `return` statement, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I completely spaced in the previous function and never returned the correct object. I just sent it right to the console. Now that I've corrected for that all is right with the world. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

This is rather a very simple task with `.reduce()` as follows;

```js
function getOldestOf(animals){
  return animals.reduce((p,c) => p.age > c.age ? p:c);
}

var animals = [ { name: 'murphy brown the dog', type: 'dog', age: 4, fav_toy: 'squeaky octopus'},
                { name: 'mervin', type: 'cat', age: 1, fav_toy: 'catnip mouse'},
                { name: 'peppercorn', type: 'cat', age: 3, fav_toy: 'lady bug pillow'},
                { name: 'willa', type: 'cat', age: 4, fav_toy: 'jingle ball'},
                { name: 'rhoda', type: 'cat', age: 14, fav_toy: 'your emotions'},
                { name: 'squatch', type: 'dog', age: 4, fav_toy: 'rope toy'},
                { name: 'maya', type: 'dog', age: 15, fav_toy: 'hedgehog'},
                { name: 'sadie', type: 'dog', age: 16, fav_toy: 'paper towel roll'},
                { name: 'max', type: 'hamster', age: 1, fav_toy: 'wooden stick'}];
console.log("My name is " + getOldestOf(animals).name);
```